# how get #th html child of an element (containing opening and closing tags of that child) with jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, numbers, children

my html code is like below :

```
    <div id="FormMessages">
        <div id="user-info-message" class="error">
            <asp:Image ID="imgError1" CssClass="imgError" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Login/Exclamation.png"
                AlternateText="attention!" ToolTip="attention!" />
            <p>
                error 1 ...</p>
        </div>
        <div id="email-message" class="error">
            <asp:Image ID="imgError2" CssClass="imgError" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Login/Exclamation.png"
                AlternateText="attention!" ToolTip="attention!" />
            <p>
                error 2 ...</p>
        </div>
        <div id="mobile-message" class="error">
            <asp:Image ID="imgError3" CssClass="imgError" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Login/Exclamation.png"
                AlternateText="attention!" ToolTip="attention!" />
            <p>
                error 3 ...</p>
        </div>
        <div id="cards-message" class="error">
            <asp:Image ID="imgError4" CssClass="imgError" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Login/Exclamation.png"
                AlternateText="attention!" ToolTip="attention!" />
            <p>
                error 4 ...</p>
        </div>
        <div id="banks-message" class="error">
            <asp:Image ID="imgError5" CssClass="imgError" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Login/Exclamation.png"
                AlternateText="attention!" ToolTip="attention!" />
            <p>
                error 5 ...</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

how can i get the #th html child (at this example -> div) of FormMessages (containing opening and closing tags of that div) with jquery?

for example i want the below html as output :

```
    <div id="mobile-message" class="error">
        <asp:Image ID="imgError3" CssClass="imgError" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Login/Exclamation.png"
            AlternateText="توجّه!" ToolTip="attention!" />
        <p>
            error 3 ...</p>
    </div>
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$("#FormMessages :nth-child(2)")` -

selects the `second child` div of the `FormMessages` div, which in this case is the div with id `email-message`.

A [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fajrP/) example.

See the documentation for the [:nth-child() Selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/).

**Edit**

Here is how you can get the second child with the starting and the opening tag -

```
alert( $('<div>')
       .append($('#FormMessages :nth-child(2)').clone())
       .remove()
       .html());
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fajrP/5/) example.

Comment: Ahmed thanks for answer / but the below code returns null -> alert($('#FormMessages:nth-child(2)').html()); and this returns an object -> alert($('#FormMessages:nth-child(2)'));

Comment: @LostLord: Forgot a space. Now it should be ok.

Comment: dear @Sayem Ahmed  : is it possible to use nth-child for this var -> var FormMessages = $('#FormMessages');

Comment: @SayemAhmed let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1122/discussion-between-lostlord-and-sayem-ahmed)

Comment: @LostLord: Sorry, office hour was finished, so I had to move out from my office. If you want to talk further, mail me at ellidan dot reize at gmail dot com :-).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the :eq selector:

```
$('#FormMessages div:eq(2)').html();
```

Comment: @Nicola Peluchetti thanks for answer -> by this way we do n't have opening and closing tags of that div...

Comment: It seems to select the third child of the `FormMessages` div: http://jsfiddle.net/fajrP/3/ . So he will have to start from zero, isn't it ?

Comment: jsfiddle is fantastic for testing jquery or javascript -> but what about opening and closing tags of that div , i want them in that alert - because i should append that html to another element??